# Открытие Windows.Explorer через IE и другие браузеры

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь открыть обычный Explorer Windows через браузер с помощью JS.

```html
<html>
 <script>
  function myFunction() 
 {
  var thePath = 'C:\\Windows';
  window.open('file://' + thePath, 'explorer');
 }
 </script>
   <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</html>
```

Пишет постоянно  `Error: Access to 'file:///C:/Windows' from script denied`. Скрипт открывается с доворенного сайта.

Используется только IE на Windows 7/10. Нужно открыть папку и/или файл.

Собственно, как заставить данный скрипт работать?

Comment: JavaScript не умеет работать с файловой системой, да и вообще он ничего не знает о железяке. Поэтому нужно это делать через сервер

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц что значит "через сервер" ?

Comment: А зачем вы хотите открыть explorer? А если у пользователя не windows? А если диска C нету?)

Comment: @Insider как я понял под словом сервер он имел виду серверный язык

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko затем чтобы показать ему где находятся файлы.. у пользователя только виндовс и диск C есть. Это 100%

Comment: @Insider боюсь Вас расстроить, но вынужден в мире существуют кроме windows еще и другие операционные системы ...

Comment: Какие файлы? Что вы хотите показать? Опишите подробнее, чего вы хотите добиться? Какая перед вами цель?

Comment: @Leks боюсь вас расстроить - это я и так знаю и знаю то, что там где это будет использоваться, есть только Windows.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko разные, .pdf, .xmls, .exe и тд - просто нужно открыть папку и показать, что мол, вот они

Comment: Понятно. Если у вас IE, то еще что-то можно придумать. В других браузерах подобное сделать нельзя.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko у всех по стандарту стоит IE и прав на установку другого нету.. так что и пришла мысть запускать либо через php или js. Но пока что не могу придти к рабочему методу.

Comment: Ну так добавьте ВСЮ информацию в вопрос. Все детали. Опишите как можно подробнее!

Comment: Как из браузера открыть папку в проводнике Windows https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/114238/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для IE вы можете использовать `ActiveX`, что бы запускать `*.exe` или открывать папки.

Возможно, понадобится [разрешить запуск](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17469/windows-internet-explorer-use-activex-controls) `ActiveX` для Internet Explorer.

```js
function runExporer(path) {
  var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var commandtoRun = path;
  oShell.ShellExecute(path, "", "", "open", "1");
}

function run() {
  runExporer("C:\\Windows\\");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">run C:\\Windows</button>
```